# Using \only in a beamer's frame with less redundancy

Tags: beamer

How to write this documents with less redundancy, specially if the number of only-items is large. I mean to reduce the number of `<i>`'s and `\center \Huge`'s expressions.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \only<1>{\center \Huge One}
        \only<2>{\center \Huge Two}
        \only<3>{\center \Huge Three}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply `\Huge` to all items, you can simply move it outside of the `\only` statements. Same goes for `\center`, however you should use `\centering` instead.

To make the code a bit easier to maintain, you could forgo the explicit overlay numbers and use relative overlays instead.This way you don't need to keep track of the numbers yourself.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \Huge
        \centering
        \only<+>{One}
        \only<+>{Two}
        \only<+>{Three}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```